# Как грамотно нормализировать базу данных

Tags: база-данных, нормализация-данных

хочу нормализовать бд. Есть таблица с полями id товара, категории товара и тд.
Так вот категорий должно быть несколько. как грамотно это все нормализовать чтобы первичным ключом остался id товара

Comment: Сделать ещё одну таблицу с двумя столбцами - id товара и id категории

Comment: @andreymal А какой первичный ключ сделать у этой таблицы? Просто id связи?

Comment: Первичный ключ в такой таблице в принципе не очень нужен. Можно повесить unique key на оба столбца для предотвращения дубликатов, но делать что-либо ещё смысла не очень много